# Is it possible to initialise an array in C++ 11 by using new operator

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, new-operator

Hi everyone i want to initialize an array in C++ like this

`int array[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};`

but i am using the new operator.

I know i can do like below and then iterate and assign the values

`shared_ptr<int[]> l (new int[7]);`

but i would really love if there is some way in which i could initialize it during the new command

something like this `shared_ptr<int[]> l (new int[7] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7});` 
but sadly this is not a valid syntax.

Also in C++ 11 standard a new STL container Array is added,can someone please tell me whether either using a normal array or the STL Array this can be achieved

Answer (score 9):

C++11 gives containers an `initializer_list` which works like this:

```
std::vector<int> array = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

`vector` is *the* dynamic array class.

---

Here's your shared_ptr version:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> ptr(new int[5]{1,2,3,4,5}, std::default_delete<int[]>());
```

Comment: but can it be done through shared_ptr and new .If yes can you please tell me how,because i need to pass the shared pointer to a function

Comment: i tried `std::vector<int> Barray = {1,2,4,6,0,0,0} ;` in my program but it is giving error at that line .Does MVS2012 support intializer list

Comment: @bourne I don't know, probably not. GCC certainly does.

Comment: Can you please explain why we have to mention `std::default_delete<int[]>()` in the line `std::shared_ptr<int> ptr(new int[5]{1,2,3,4,5}, std::default_delete<int[]>());`

Comment: @bourne `shared_ptr` isn't specialized for `int[]` like `unique_ptr` is, and so it would call `delete` rather than `delete[]` without it. Keep in mind that `shared_ptr` wasn't intended for storing dynamic arrays.

Comment: @Pubby boost has shared_array instead of shared_ptr for that. is there shared_array in std?

Comment: @Slava no, there isn't any `shared_array` in the standard library at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to C++11 and uniform initialization, you can:

```
int main()
{
    int* p = new int[10] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    // ...
    delete[] p;
}
```

[live demo](http://ideone.com/4U9zcu)