# Is it possible to initialise an array of non-POD with operator new and initialiser syntax?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, clang, initializer-list

I have just read and understood [Is it possible to initialise an array in C++ 11 by using new operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183671/is-it-possible-to-initialise-an-array-in-c-11-by-using-new-operator), but it does not quite solve my problem.

This code gives me a compile error in Clang:

```
struct A
{
   A(int first, int second) {}
};
void myFunc()
{
   new A[1] {{1, 2}};
}
```

I expected {{1, 2}} to initialise the array with a single element, in turn initialised with the constructor args {1, 2}, but I get this error:

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'A'
   new A[1] {{1, 2}};
            ^
note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 0 were provided
   A(int first, int second) {}
   ^
note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
struct A
       ^
```

Why does this syntax not work?

Comment: Because `A` does not accept an initializer list as the sole parameter to its constructor. `{1, 2}` is an `std::initializer_list`, `(1,2)` is two separate parameters, they're very different things.

Comment: FYI, g++4.9 accepts this program.

Comment: @Arman `{1, 2}` is a *braced-init-list*. Braced-init-lists do not have to call `initializer_list` constructors. Braced-init-lists are more general, they're part of *uniform initialization*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This seems to be [clang++ bug 15735](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=15735). Declare a default constructor (making it accessible and not deleted) and the program compiles, even though the default constructor is not called:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
   A() { std::cout << "huh?\n"; } // or without definition, linker won't complain
   A(int first, int second) { std::cout << "works fine?\n"; }
};
int main()
{
   new A[1] {{1, 2}};
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1edfb5cd1dcd0842)

g++4.9 also accepts the OP's program without modifications.