# Xcode 7.3 and C++11 support

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11

I've been trying out some examples from C++ Tutorial from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) and I stumbled upon this code:

```
// pointer to classes example
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Rectangle {
    int width, height;
public:
    Rectangle(int x, int y) : width(x), height(y) {}
    int area(void) { return width * height; }
};


int main() {
    Rectangle obj (3, 4);
    Rectangle * foo, * bar, * baz;
    foo = &obj;
    bar = new Rectangle (5, 6);
    baz = new Rectangle[2] { {2,5}, {3,6} };
    cout << "obj's area: " << obj.area() << '\n';
    cout << "*foo's area: " << foo->area() << '\n';
    cout << "*bar's area: " << bar->area() << '\n';
    cout << "baz[0]'s area:" << baz[0].area() << '\n';
    cout << "baz[1]'s area:" << baz[1].area() << '\n';
    delete bar;
    delete[] baz;
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run it using Xcode 7.3 I always receive an error:

```
No matching constructor for initialization of 'Rectangle'
```

referring to this line of the code:

```
baz = new Rectangle[2] { {2,5}, {3,6} };
```

Basing on what I've managed to find online, this kind of usage of "new []" is supported in C++11 and up. The problem is that my project is set up for using this standard.

[image]

I've tried all possible options available for "C++ Language Dialect" and "C++ Standard Library" - to no avail.

I'd be very thankful for any help.

Comment: This is a good question, and I don't know the answer. But I wonder if that initializer is valid in C++14 but not C++11?

Comment: It is valid in both C++11 and C++14, at least [link](http://cpp.sh) compiles it just fine.

Comment: Try explicitly declaring the default constructer. In other words, add the default constructor `Rectangle(){}` to the `Rectangle` class.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but it isn't really the issue. This code up is correct and compiles with no problem but not in case of Xcode and that's what I'm trying to solve here.

Comment: Does not compile using clang 3.4 on FreeBSD (-std=c++11). Nor in os x in terminal.

Comment: Which version of gcc/g++ is your Xcode using? It might be outdated.

Comment: Ok... I guess I know what seems to be the problem: clang. I didn't even notice that Xcode hasn't been including gcc/g++ since a while but has been shipped with clang. I checked the code on [link](http://rextester.com) and it doesn't work with clang indeed, whilst when using gcc - works like a charm.

Comment: I played 'hunt the bug' and it looks like: https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=15735 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676935/is-it-possible-to-initialise-an-array-of-non-pod-with-operator-new-and-initialis

Comment: @Jakub: How did you set up C++11 in Xcode in the first place? I spent hours trying to find that setting (How do I get to the screenshot you posted?).